# <a> element styled button is scrolling down my web page

Tags: html, css, button

I've been trying to force my button to not scroll down/up to the linked element and just produce the button's animation without any success!

I've tried the jquery's  preventDefault(among many other things) but this would not let the animation to actually work

Here is the code
[Code in codepen](https://codepen.io/david-ricardo-bor/pen/xWNKRb)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 120%;
  background-color: gray;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}


/*Buttons style; button_input is for the sepcial inputs*/

.button {
  top-margin: 1rem;
}

.button_input {
  width: 140px;
}

.male>span {
  right: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.female>span {
  left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.bg {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.bg2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.icon::before,
.icon::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
}

.male .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/man.png");
  background-position: center;
}

.female .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/woman.png");
  background-position: center;
}

.bg::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.75rem;
  left: -4.75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover .bg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

.bg:target {
  animation: push 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#male:target {
  background-color: #003D79;
}

#female:target {
  background-color: #003D79;
}

.bg:target::before,
.bg:target::after {
  animation: wave 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bg:target::before {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.bg:target::after {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.bg2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.75rem;
  left: -4.75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover .bg2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

.bg2:target {
  animation: push 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.bg2:target::before,
.bg2:target::after {
  animation: waves 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bg2:target::before {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.bg2:target::after {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes push {
  15% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #2EB4FF;
  }
}

@keyframes waves {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #FF99CC;
  }
}


/*Espacios para el td de la opción géneros */

table.table td.genders {
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='3'>
      <h5 class='StepTitle'>Partaker's Gender</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' class="genders">
      <a class="button male" href="#male">
        <span class="bg" id="male"></span>
        <span class="symbol"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="button female" href="#female">
        <span class="bg2" id="female"></span>
        <span class="icon"></span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have 2 `id='male'` only one is allowed. `:target` pseudoclass only targets an `#id` selector so `.bg:target` is invalid as well.

Comment: Hi @zer00ne , do you mean in the codepen? I added the other id in order to try the below answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scrolling behavior is baked into the `:target` pseudo selector, since the browser's default is to scroll the targeted `id` to the top of the window.

Using `jQuery`'s `toggleClass` method would be a pretty simple solution. However, if you want to use pure `CSS` there are a couple workarounds. One is to place an absolutely positioned element and add the `id` for the element you're targeting to it.

A second option is to use the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), where you use styled labels for a hidden checkbox instead.

Hope this helps!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Buttons style; button_input is for the sepcial inputs*/

.button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.button_input {
  width: 140px;
}

.male>span {
  right: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.icon {
  left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.icon::before,
.icon::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
}

.male .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/man.png");
  background-position: center;
}

.female .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/woman.png");
  background-position: center;
}

.bg::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.75rem;
  left: -4.75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover .bg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

.bg2::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.75rem;
  left: -4.75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover .bg2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
}

@keyframes push {
  15% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #2EB4FF;
  }
}

@keyframes waves {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #FF99CC;
  }
}


/*Espacios para el td de la opción géneros */

table.table td.genders {
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}

//checkbox hack
#toggle-male,
#toggle-female {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* toggled state */


/* male animation */

#toggle-male:checked~.bg {
  animation: push 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  background-color: #003D79;
}

#toggle-male:checked~.bg::before,
#toggle-male:checked~.bg::after {
  animation: waves 1s ease-in-out;
}

#toggle-male:checked~.bg::before {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#toggle-male:checked~.bg1::after {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}


/* female animations */

#toggle-female:checked~.bg2 {
  animation: push 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  background-color: #003D79;
}

#toggle-female:checked~.bg2::before,
#toggle-female:checked~.bg2::after {
  animation: waves 1s ease-in-out;
}

#toggle-female:checked~.bg2::before {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#toggle-female:checked~.bg2::after {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='3'>
      <h5 class='StepTitle'>Partaker's Gender</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' width="100px" class="genders">
      <a class="button male" id="male">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-male">
        <label for="toggle-male" class="bg"></label>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td align='center' width="100px" class="genders">
      <a class="button female" id="female">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-female">
        <label for="toggle-female" class="bg2"></label>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:**

Here's an example with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bgs').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('animate background').toggleClass('animateAft');
    if ($('.bgs').hasClass('animate background' || 'animateAft')) {
      $('.bgs').not(this).removeClass('animate background').removeClass('animateAft');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.button {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.button_input {
  width: 140px;
}

.icon {
  left: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.icon::before,
.icon::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
}

.male .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/man.png");
  background-position: center;
}

.female .icon::after {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("../images/woman.png");
  background-position: center;a
}

.bgs {
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg:after,
.bg2:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4.75rem;
  left: -4.75rem;
  display: block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  transform: scale(0.4);
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate {
  animation: push 1s ease-out;
}

.background {
  transition: background .4s ease;
  background-color: #003D79;
}

.bg.animateAft:after,
.bg2.animateAft:after {
  animation: waves 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bg.animateAft:before,
bg2.animateAft:before {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.bg.animateAft:after,
.bg2.animateAft:after {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes push {
  15% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #2EB4FF;
  }
}

@keyframes waves {
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0
  }
  from {
    background-color: #FF99CC;
  }
}

/*Espacios para el td de la opción géneros */

table.table td.genders {
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='3'>
      <h5 class='StepTitle'>Partaker's Gender</h5>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align='center' width="100px" class="genders">
      <a class="button male" id="male">
            <span id="toggle-male" class="bgs bg"></span>
          </a>
    </td>
    <td align='center' width="100px" class="genders">
      <a class="button female" id="female">
            <span id="toggle-female" class="bgs bg2"></span>
          </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your answer, it was really helpful! and how could it be done with the .toggleClass()?

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I cannot see the buttons within the jsfiddle link...? I'd really like to up-vote your answer but unfortunately I don't have the reputation  level required!

Comment: I just added a jQuery example to my answer here.

Comment: Pretty awesome @Mark thank you for time and answers! You have really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes fix this, by adding an invisible div, upper from your real target... and then target `<a>` to that invis div:

Like this:

```
<div id="BUBU" style="position: absolute; margin-top: -100px; display: none;"></div>

<a href="#BUBU"> ... </a>
<span class="REAL-TARGET"></span>
```

Comment: Hi there, I added the div above my code but it would not trigger the animation! you can check  your solution up in my codepen link